# When will the iPad get threaded email messages?

Tags: ipad, ios, email

I use my iPhone and iPad to check emails, and would really like to have the threaded email functionality on my iPad the same as it is on my iPhone? Will this be available in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one of the features of iOS 4.2, which will be released [in November](http://www.apple.com/ipad/software-update/).

Comment: To quote from that page "Even better Mail
See messages from all your accounts in a unified inbox, organize messages by threads, and open attachments in third-party apps."

Comment: I'm running the beta of 4.2 on my iPad, and the Unified Inbox feature is definitely there. So awesome.